# Nobody knows when God will come again, but do we technically know when He will not come?

Tags: revelation, second-coming

Since in Revelations there are signs and things that must happen before God comes, do we technically know that God will not come before those things happen? So unless we are living in the end end times that Revelation describes, it's not like every day God could possibly come?

Comment: Such is the nature of the Apocalypse that nobody - but nobody - can categorically prove that any one event within it, or the totality of all the events within it, have not already happened. The addition of the word 'technically' to the question above does not, in any way, clarify the situation. No, we don't know _when_ and no, we don't know _not when_. "At such a time as ye think not" will _always_ be true.

Comment: There is no mention of God coming until the new earth, which is a long time after Jesus returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, I'd like to suggest that the book of the **Revelation makes clear the possibility that the Lord's spectacular and sudden return could happen in any given generation of Christians** after the apostle John received the visions at the end of the first century A.D.

Indeed, the entire book is designed to enable all Christians to maintain faith in the return, so as to be found withstanding the satanic deception that will precede the Day of Resurrection and Judgment.

As "judgment begins with the house of God" (1 Peter 4:17), the Revelation starts with Christ's warnings of his church being inspected. Then various 'seals' are opened, the first four using symbolic language of different coloured horses and their riders to show what woes would be symbolically galloping over all the earth after Christ going forth, crowned, on a white horse, to conquer (without sword or arrows) those to be gathered unto him. Christ continues to ride forth in that role to this very day, as do the others in their destructive roles. But by the end of the Revelation the horsemen have completed their thousands of years of going to and fro, and Christ rides a white horse in a different role. He leads a company of angelic hosts, to destroy his enemies in righteous wrath. By then, it will be too late for anybody to seek to turn to Christ (Rev. 19:11-16 & 19).

Because of the satanic deception at work among all the nations during "the little season" before the day of wrath, only those who belong to Christ by faith will be able to know what it is they are to avoid, if they are to remain true to Christ to the end. They do not need a timetable, nor will anybody get one. Their eyes are fixed on Christ, and the world's allurements and deceptions do not trip them up. They live by faith, not by sight. They come out of the monstrous evil systems that are spiritual, before God causes them to come suddenly crashing down.

Whether that destruction at God's hand comes in their lifetime, or generations later, does not matter. Their calling is to be faithful to their Lord, who might suddenly come at any time. But even if that return does not happen in their lifetime, they have done what the Revelation said by taking seriously its message to endure, despite persecutions and ridicule. Certainly this generation has seen more total persecution and ridicule of Christians than any previous one, so that is something to be aware of.

The opening admonition holds as good today as it did when first penned 1,928 years ago:

> "Blessed is he that readeth, and they that hear the words of this
> prophecy, and keep those things which are written therein: for the
> time is at hand." Rev. 1:3
>
> "Seal not the sayings of the prophecy of this book: for the time is at
> hand." Rev. 22:10

The time was at hand when John wrote the prophecy down, and has been "at hand" in every generation of Christians following. That is because every generation of Christians must remain faithful to the gospel of Christ, and to the words of that prophecy, for the return could happen at any time. It will even take many Christians by surprise, for many today are foolishly lulled into a false sense of security, supposing that (according to their interpretation of events) Christ will not be likely to come in their life-time. Those ones are wide open to being deceived by the great satanic deception that will happen globally, shortly before that return. We have been warned, in love, by the One who we must keep our eyes of faith on at all times.

Given what Jesus said here, ***only a fool would say, "Oh, the Lord will not return in this decade, or this year, or this week."***

> Matthew 24:44 - "Be ye also ready, for in such an hour as ye think not
> the Son of man cometh."
>
> Revelation 3:2-3 - "Be watchful, and strengthen the things which
> remain... and repent. If therefore thou shalt not watch, I will come
> on thee as as thief, and though shalt not know what hour I will come
> upon thee."

Comment: Totally agree. Up-voted +1. This agrees with Paul's writings also and with the parables of Jesus of Nazareth.

Answer (score 0):

We do have the statement by Paul that "the day of the Lord" will not come "unless the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of perdition, who opposes and sets himself against [all forms of worship]" (2 Thessalonians ch2 vv3-4, RSV).

This looks like a summary of the central issue of the book of Revelation, viz. a crisis of hostility against God and his worshippers. much more extreme than anything we've seen so far. The Revelation narrative is that Christ returns as the final answer to this crisis, which certainly implies that he won't come before the crisis has started.

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question. This shifts the focus to a different prophesy but the same principle remains that we can never be absolutely certain that our perception is correct regarding the time in which we live.

Comment: The two prophecies are on the same theme. It is not easy for a good perspective to see Revelation ch13 as being already fulfilled at the resent time.

Comment: I see the contents of Revelation 13 being present throughout the Church Age, myself, from the ascension to the return of Christ - an abiding principle of opposition to the ascended son-bachelor.

Answer (score 0):

One compelling view of prophecy proposed by some is that it is fractal. The same patterns occur at shorter and longer time frames. In this way, God disguises when the final instance of the pattern will be impressed upon history.

For example, take the opening of the seven seals of the scroll of Revelation. The first four seals are the four horsemen of the apocalypse (war, civil war, pestilence and death), followed by the fifth, a great persecution. Byzantium was devastated by attacks from the east. Then it went through two centuries of civil war. Then the early fourteenth century had a terrible famine, followed by the even worse Black Death. The plague returned dozens of times over the next century. Then Constantinople fell to the Ottomans and millions of Christians died or were forced to convert to Islam in a massive persecution. This all followed the pattern of Revelation, but the end did not come. The pattern faded and the remaining signs did not happen.

The same pattern afflicted the Roman Catholic Church, but it started later and lasted longer. The war was the fall of Constantinople, serving as the starting point not the end of the cycle. The civil war was the Protestant Reformation and subsequent General Crisis of the 17th Century. The pestilence and rising prices for food were the Industrial Revolution and rise of Capitalism. The death was WW1, Influenza epidemic, Communism, Nazism, WW2, Great Leap Forward, and other calamities of the 20th century. If this pattern continues, we can expect a great persecution of Christians later in this century. Will it be the final example? Or will the next afflict not the church, but the whole world?

I believe that each repetition of the cycle will match more prophetic details than the one before it. However, each will include crises so terrifying that many Christians will believe that the end is almost here. It is by bending history to frequently resemble the last days that God will conceal his ultimate timetable.

The preceding only deals with the seven seals. Another pattern of judgment is based on the Ten Plagues on Egypt and the Ten Commandments. I have discovered historical parallels that show God also judges civilizations according to the Ten Commandments with Plagues similar in goals (though different in details) to the plagues on Egypt. The same pattern repeats. The template is Egypt, where the plagues lasted from one month to one year. You can also see that they apply to a series of ten empires (Babel, Egypt, Israel, Assyria, Babylon, Medo-Persia, Greece, Rome, Islam, and a future empire) with each being judged for breaking the next commandment in sequence.

I also divided the history of Israel from Joshua entering the Promised Land to the birth of Christ into ten eras of equal duration, 150 years. Each era saw a judgment that matches the corresponding Plague/Commandment. The same applies to the Church, from the birth of Christ to the present and into the future, with each era running for 240 years. The church was judged by analogous judgments. (For example, the plague of boils matches the time of the Black Death, which presented as boils, and the commandment against murder.)

Most of the plagues on Egypt show up in Revelation. Thus any civilization, as it falls under God’s judgment, will meet its end in a sequence that bears some comparison to what befell Egypt long ago. When people spot such concordance, they will assume that the end of the world is near. It may be the end of their world, but for others history will continue - until one day it doesn’t.

(This analysis of the Ten Commandments, Ten plagues on Egypt and the rise and fall of civilizations is the subject of an upcoming book I am writing.)

Answer (score 0):

Many organizations and individuals have published lists that describe prophecies that are expected to be fulfilled *before* Christ will return.

One example is this 42 page booklet,
[*Fourteen Signs Announcing Christ's Return* (Living Church of God)](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/fourteen-signs-announcing-christs-return),
which lists:

1. Wars, Violence, and Lawlessness
2. Drought and Famine
3. Earthquakes and Other Natural Catastrophes
4. Disease Epidemics
5. The Rise of an Aggressive, Fundamentalist Islamic Power
6. An Ascendant European Union Seeks Global Primacy
7. A Powerful Religious Figure Leads a Religious Revival
8. The Gospel of the Kingdom of God Preached to All Nations
9. Faith Again Becomes a Matter of Life or Death
10. A Crisis Strikes Jerusalem
11. The Abomination of Desolation
12. The Great Tribulation — The Collapse of the English-Speaking Nations
13. Heavenly Signs and the Day of the Lord
14. The Seven Last Plagues

Other lists will differ, but will be similar.

The key prophecy though is Matthew 24, and in particular, verse 22:

> And unless those days were shortened, no flesh would be saved; but for the elect’s sake those days will be shortened.

It's not until that last moment just before mankind totally destroys itself, that Christ will return to prevent it.

There are two important things to consider though.

As we have seen in recent world events, the time lapse between good times and catastrophe can be quite short; when the end comes it will be sudden, despite one's already knowing that it will happen.

And even if nothing happens for decades or centuries, people can still experience their own personal "end of the world".

> Or those eighteen on whom the tower in Siloam fell and killed them, do you think that they were worse sinners than all other men who dwelt in Jerusalem?
> I tell you, no; but unless you repent you will all likewise perish.

One can die at any moment.
Without warning, one can be living a normal life, and an eye-blink later be part of the resurrection at Christ's return.
One should continuously be prepared for this eventuality, rather than worrying about when the big event will happen; for you, it might be today.

Answer (score 0):

**Nobody knows when God will come again, but do we technically know when He will not come?**

> Let no one deceive you in any way. For that day will not come, unless the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of destruction. - [2 Thessalonians 2:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/2%20Thessalonians%202%3A3)

The *”man of lawlessness”* in 2 Thessalonians 2:1–12 is obviously the Antichrist who will come on the world scene at the beginning of the Day of the Lord.

The **two witnesses** must also appear, before that *Day of the Lord*, as mentioned in the Book of Revelation.

> And I will grant my two witnesses authority to prophesy for one thousand two hundred sixty days, wearing sackcloth.” - [Revelation 11:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+11%3A1-13&version=NRSVUE)